# read csv file data and store it in database using spring framework

Tags: spring, spring-framework-beans

I need help, I want the code to read the data which is in a csv file and the store that data into database. I have tried reading the csv file with known rows and cols. But the challenge here is that I want to create an utility where I don't know the number of cols and rows that are in the csv file so how would I do it? Please help.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please go through the link on how to ask effective questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored `Spring Batch`? You can write your own implementation of `LineTokenizer` for the columns which are going to change dynamically.